# UITableView Separator inset should be transparent, but is white

Tags: ios, uitableview, interface-builder

I need some help. I have a custom separator color of dark grey. For some reason, I'm getting a white separator above the sections, and the separator inset is white.

My layout is: A `UITableView` within a `UIView` within a normal `UIViewController`.

I've already tried these things:

- Set separator inset to 0. This will make the white separator inset shorter, but it is still there. ?
- Set the background colors of the table and the containing view to black. This didn't work.
- For the `UITableViewCell`, I can set

  ```
  cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
  ```

  and

  ```
  cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
  ```

and then the white separator inset will disappear, but the grey separator goes to the edge of the screen. I still need a separator inset that matches the black background.

Here is what I see:

[image: Bad Separator Inset]

Comment: This is not a duplicate - This post IS NOT THE SAME as the other post because that guy wants to simply remove the separator inset. Easy. If you read my question it is clear that I want to keep the separator inset, but just make it match the background color and not white. I actually read that post and it did not help in the slightest. Read the things I said I tried - it didn't work!

Comment: Flagging for moderator review to remove "marked as duplicate"